Part name of this IC - "5CTI PSZQ"
I want to know the part numbers of the components marked as shown in the attached image. "5CTI PSZQ" and  "OM TI MAP"




Some context might be helpful - what it's in, what it's connected to,  etc...

The IC with "PFKI" label is TPS60400DBVR 60mA charge pump voltage inverter in SOT23-5 packaging. The IC with "TI MAP" label is LM2903DGKR dual differential comparator in VSSOP8 packaging.
I suggest you use Google search to find the identity of the parts.

It's a Texas Instruments TPS7A3001DG negative voltage regulator.


(Source: lcsc.com)

Can you also show me the IC code marked "PFKI" and " OC TI MAP" in the same picture?

@BangDuong Like I said before, you should only ask for one part in a question (I know enforcement is inconsistent). You also shouldn't edit your question to add additional parts. Lastly, OC TI MAP is clearly another Texas Instruments part (the other one as well but it's less obvious), it will be easy to find by just googling Texas Instruments "MAP" marking.

In a component cluster, if someone knows the component code, they will observe the entire cluster to know the other codes, so I attach a photo. I will take note for next time. Thanks.

Nope. Knowing one component marking does not mean that someone knows another arbitrary component marking.

I will take note for next time. Thanks.
